# Can I tile a texture on a RectangleShape?

Tags: c++, sfml, texture2d

I have a rectangleshape that can change size in a program of mine (I won't copy it here as it is too large), and I have assigned a 64x64 pixel texture to it. The shape itself is much larger than the texture, but the texture just gets spread over the whole shape. Is there a way to change it so that the texture remains 64x64, but tiles across the rectangleshape?

Comment: Use [`sf::Texture::setRepeated(true)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26517408/2683574)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how to do it, I just had to use the line

```
tex.setRepeated(true);
```

and the line

```
rect.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, xRect, yRect));
```

with xRect and yRect being the dimensions of the rectangleobject, tex bing the texture name and and rect being the rectangle object that the texture has been assigned to.